# How to set the out of office autoreply with applescript?

Tags: outlook, applescript

Trying to figure out how to use Applescript to toggle the Outlook autoreply option from off/on and vice versa.

I can query the status with

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"

query autoreply data exchange account 1

end tell
```

This works fine (although it returns the entire property list, and I only need the enabled element).  The bigger problem is that I'm just not sure how to set the parameters with `set autoreply data`, as I'm not sure of the formatting of the command.

Appears in the dictionary as

```
set autoreply data v
set autoreply data exchange account
new data autoreply data
```

with the parameters of:

```
autoreply data n
properties
enabled (boolean) : Whether autoreplies are sent
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by getting the entire property list into a variable, toggling the enabled field, and then sending the property list back to Outlook.

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"

    set theResult to query autoreply data exchange account 0

    if enabled of theResult is false then
        set enabled of theResult to true
    else
        set enabled of theResult to false
    end if

    set autoreply data exchange account 0 new data theResult

end tell
```